# Pourquoi dit-on "faire le Jacques" pour parler d'une action stupide ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Pourquoi dit-on "**faire le Jacques**" pour parler d'une action stupide ? Pourquoi "Jacques" et non "Jean" ou "Louis"... ?

Voyons, chef, je vous le demande : est-ce mon rôle d'aller **faire le Jacques** et de répandre de l'encre sur le cahier de décisions pour sauver la mise à deux gouapes? (Courteline, Gaietés esc.,1886, VII, 2, p. 98).

Nous ne devons point le tromper pour le plaisir de **faire les jacques** (Péguy, Porche Myst.,1911, p. 238).

J'ai **fait le jacques**, j'ai quitté mon père, qui est ouvrier brocheur, pour faire du théâtre (Colette, Music-hall,1913, p. 62).

Answer (score 3):

Comme le dit @XouDo il faut rapprocher l'expression « faire le jacques » de la [Grande Jacquerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Jacquerie) de 1358. Ce mouvement tire son nom du sobriquet « jacques » donné par les nobles aux paysans français, plus exactement à ceux de l'Île de France et du Beauvaisis, où a justement démarré la Grande Jacquerie de 1358. Pour les nobles les paysans étaient des idiots, des gens qui agissaient de façon stupide.

Selon les sources ce surnom viendrait soit du fait que le nom Jacques était fréquent parmi les paysans de la région où a démarré la Grande Jacquerie<sup>1</sup>, soit du vêtement appelé « jacque »(lequel plus tard a donné « jacquette »)<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Article [Grande Jacquerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Jacquerie) de Wikipedia.</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

Ci-dessous la définition du Cnrtl :

> − Loc. Faire le jacques (parfois avec majuscule). Faire l'imbécile, agir stupidement.

Et il faut probablement chercher du coté de l'histoire de France (toujours Cnrtl) :

> A. −
>
> 1. HIST. DE FRANCE. [Avec une majuscule] Participant de la Jacquerie de 1358. L'émeute était aussi dans les campagnes où la misère
>    soulevait ceux qu'on appelait « les Jacques » (Druon, Lis et
>    Lion,1960, p. 380).V. Jacquerie ex. 1.

Quand au pourquoi de "Jacques" plutôt qu'un autre prénom, on trouve ça :

> c'est le prénom Jacques qui, appliqué comme sobriquet pendant le cours
> de la 1remoitié du XIVes. aux vilains et gens de campagne, donna
> presque aussitôt naissance (...) au mot jacquerie qui n'a pas cessé
> dep. lors d'être synon. d'insurrection rustique

On peut supposer que le prénom Jacques était très courant chez les paysans de cet époque.

Suite à la célébrité de la Jacquerie, on peut imaginer une influence sur le sens initial de Jacques pour désigner la désobéissance et le refus de l'autorité, en plus de la rusticité. (Pour moi l'utilisation actuelle de *faire le Jacques* porte cette connotation, que j'entends souvent à propos d'enfant turbulents)

---

Après quelques recherches supplémentaire, je note que certains sites indiquent que ce sens de Jacques proviendrait de l'anglais (plus précisément de Shakespeare) [cf. l'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/6414/faire-le-jacques/) :

> Cette expression date de 1880. A l'époque, le prénom Jacques servait à désigner un simple d'esprit.
> Cette locution peut également faire référence à un jeu anglais, « to play the Jack » - utilisé par Shakespeare, qui consistait à faire des farces.

On évoque cette étymologie aussi [ici](https://www.etymo-logique.com/le-mot-du-jour/personnalites/jacquier-gilles/) et [là](https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/cinq-prenoms-maltraites-par-la-langue-francaise-20190901), mais toujours sans référence précise, je ne sais quel crédit lui accorder.

Comment: Il semblerait que ce soit du surnom de jacques donné aux paysans que le terme de jacquerie soit issu et pas le contraire.

Comment: @None La réponse de XouDo laisse entendre que *Jacquerie* a pu donner *Jacques* ?

Comment: @jlliagre je trouve le déroulé de la réponse ambigu,  je comprends  « ... on imagine donc bien le glissement possible ... »  comme un glissement de jacquerie vers jacques (et non de jacques vers jacquerie). Me trompé-je ?

Comment: @None Les deux citations indiquent clairement qui à donné quoi. Je comprends le glissement comme étant celui de *Jacques/Jacquerie* (idiot des campagnes, aujourd'hui on dirait *plouc*) vers *idiot en général*.

Comment: @jlliagre Les citations ne sont que des citations, pas le point de vue du PO à laquelle je me réfère !

Comment: @None Les citations font partie de la réponse et Jacques arrive avant Jacquerie. Je ne comprends donc pas du tout sa phrase comme toi, d'autant plus que l'idée que Jacquerie ait pu donner Jacques me semble tellement absurde que je ne pourrais pas soupçonner quelqu'un de le penser.

Comment: @jlliagre Dans mon idée, la célébrité de la Jacquerie avait pu peser sur le sens du Jacques préexistant de *Idiot des campagne* vers Idiot en général voire idiot nuisible ou personne mettant le bazar, voyou que je percevais (peut-être à tort) dans le Jacques actuel.

Comment: Oui, je vois ça comme ça aussi, mais je n'utilise pas l'expression *faire le Jacques* tous les jours. C'est plus proche de *jamais*... Mon commentaire se rapportait plutôt à l'impossibilité pour un mot dérivé d'un autre d'être antérieur à ce dernier. L'œuf et la poule...